# Laravel 8 Eloquent ORM Login Process

Tags: laravel, authentication, eloquent

I want to do login system using Eloquent ORM in laravel 8.

```
 $data = User::where('email',$email)->where('password',$password)->get();
```

How can i check $data have value ?

```
 if($data hasValue)
     {
      dd('login');
    
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure your passwords aren't stored in plain text.

Try this:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash; // place this at the very top

$user = User::where('email', '=', $email)->first();

if( $user && Hash::check($password, $user->password) ) {
   dd( 'login' );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to authenticate users manually, you can do something like this:

```php
public function authenticate(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        $request->session()->regenerate();

        return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
    }

    return back()->withErrors([
        'email' => 'The provided credentials do not match our records.',
    ]);
}
```

This is straight from the Laravel docs BTW: https://laravel.com/docs/authentication#authenticating-users